# Schedule open automator application every days works only one time

Tags: automator, calendar, macos

I'm using macOS Sierra and I have a strange problem: I'm trying to schedule Automator & a Calendar event to open up a file every day when a recurring calendar event occurs. But the Automator workflow only runs the first day!

**Here's how I made it**:
I created the event in the Calendar app on the calendar "Automator" (local on my Mac). I made a recurring event in the calendar that shows up daily at 7 AM. Then, I created an automator workflow to open this file (which is an automator file that opens a URL in Safari) every time the event goes off, but it only runs & opens up the file the first time the recurring event occurs in the Calendar, not the rest of the times.

**How can I get the Automator workflow to run each time this calendar event recurs instead of just the first time?**

[image]

Comment: Just make a recurring event with your Calendar app!

Comment: Of course I made a recurring event all days, I forgot write it!

Comment: Your question really confuses me. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: It's very simple, I want to schedule to open a file every day.
I've created an event with an alarm for open the file, and it works perfectly, but only the first day. The other events inside the calendar with the same alarm won't open the file...

Comment: That was totally unclear from your question, so I've edited it now. Do you mind describing your Automator workflow in detail so we can help you diagnose the issue? Screenshots or a detailed description of the Automator workflow in the question would help, then comment back once you've done that.

Comment: I simply create an application file with automator for open a url and show the result in safari. It works every time I double click on the file I've created.
Then, I've created an event inside a calendar on my mac, and the event have to open the file every day at 7:00 am. It works only the first time, the other days anything happens

Comment: We are in May 2019, and i have the same issue as you describe. My Automator App only launch ONE time in Calendar … also if i create manually enent every day … ! Since 2017, maybe you did found a solution ? If so, i'm very interrested to know what it is ? ! Best regards, DW (sorry for my imperfect english)

Comment: @MERLiN did you make sure you saved the changes for all future events?